# Разрешения файлов и chmod Linux Mint

Tags: linux, файлы, linux-mint, permissions

У меня есть файл "filee" владельцем которого я и являюсь, у меня есть права на его чтение и запись, но нет разрешения на запуск.
По этому я решил использовать chmode в абсолютном режиме для изменения прав - `sudo chmod 764 filee`, никаких ошибок не возникло но права не поменялись.
Помогите разобраться почему эта команда не работает, и в чем я ошибся.
На этом изображении показана последовательность выполнения моих команд:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/809274410049339452/822746972023947294/2021-03-20_17-21-42.png

Comment: Все действия лучше в тексте выкладывайте. Пока совсем не очевидно почему команда не отрабатывает.
Попробуйте аналогично `chmod u+rwx filee `

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но и в этом случае ничего не изменилось. Из директории с файлом я выполнил эту команду но права не поменялись

Comment: Ну судя по всему вы пытаетесь сменить права на файле, который расположен на другой файловой системе, смонтированной скорее всего с `noexec`.

Comment: Да нет, у меня есть винчестер на котором и стоит сама Linux Mint, и там же раздел X-Files где располагаться этот файл. Больше на диске ничего нет

Comment: Причем у некоторых файлах удается изменить разрешение но не у всех, может быть дело в файловой системе тома msdos?

Comment: Ну логично, другая ФС с другими критериями прав.

Comment: В этом и оказалось проблема, файловая система в моем разделе была FAT32, и насколько я понимаю средства Linux плохо с ней работают. По этому я посчитал лучшим решением изменить ее на exFAT. после чего все решилось, спасибо за помощь.